# wget: don't follow redirects

Tags: linux, http, bash, redirect, wget

How do I prevent *wget* from following redirects?

Comment: 301 redirects in my case `wget --mirror http://some.url` where `index?q=1` is saved as a duplicate of `/pretty/urls/` despite the initial request for index returning a HTTP 301 Moved Permanently redirect.

Answer (score 62):

`--max-redirect 0`

I haven't tried this, it will either allow none or allow infinite..

Comment: I think you can also do --level=1 or -l=1 to do 1 level of redirection.  --level=0 is the same as --level=inf, which is infinite.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work if you want to retrieve the response body of a redirect...

Comment: Just had occasion to try it; `--max-redirect 0` allows none, *not* infinite.

Comment: `--max-redirect 0` fails with `0 redirections exceeded.` on my old wget 1.12. So it does not suppress redirects but fails when they happen. `curl` works.

Comment: btw `--level` is for recursion (following *links*, not redirects).

Comment: This fails with `0 redirections exceeded.`

Comment: what about wget of alpine  ?

Comment: @AbdennourTOUMI alpine uses the BusyBox wget, which isn't really a full wget anyway. If you check [the source](https://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/networking/wget.c?h=1_33_stable#n1141) then you'll see `redir_limit` is hardcoded to 16. I don't see any parameter that would change this

Answer (score 17):

Use `curl` without `-L` instead of `wget`. Omitting that option when using `curl` prevents the redirect from being followed.

If you use `curl -I <URL>` then you'll get the headers instead of the redirect HTML.

If you use `curl -IL <URL>` then you'll get the headers for the URL, plus those for the URL you're redirected to.

Comment: in my environment wget has more access than curl

Comment: I tried to download the favicon at `prisonexp.org` and I was denied access.  wget had no problem according to an SO user so I'm implementing that now.

Comment: `curl -I` is even better: it just prints the headers.

Comment: @Colin'tHart: I added some information to my answer. Thanks.

Comment: The question is about `wget`, not `curl`.

Answer (score 7):

Some versions of `wget` have a `--max-redirect` option: See [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/HTTP-Options.html)

Answer (score 3):

wget follows up to 20 redirects by default. However, it does not span hosts. If you have asked wget to download `example.com`, it will not touch any resources at `www.example.com`. wget will detect this as a request to span to another host and decide against it.

In short, you should probably be executing:

```
wget --mirror www.example.com
```

Rather than

```
wget --mirror example.com
```

Now let's say the owner of `www.example.com` has several subdomains at `example.com` and we are interested in all of them. How to proceed?

Try this:

```
wget --mirror --domains=example.com example.com
```

wget will now visit all subdomains of example.com, including `m.example.com` and `www.example.com`.

Comment: uh... not using mirror, just want the header from a 302, don't want it to follow the 302.  how do i do that?

Comment: It "does not span hosts" only in spider mode.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question: it will still follow 301 or 302 responses within the website. As the asker mentions, he just wants the headers.

Answer (score 3):

In general, it is not a good idea to depend on a specific number of redirects.

For example, in order to download IntellijIdea, the URL that is promised to always resolve to the latest version of Community Edition for Linux is something like `https://download.jetbrains.com/product?code=IIC&latest&distribution=linux`, but if you visit that URL nowadays, you are going to be redirected twice (2 times) before you reach the actual downloadable file. In the future you might be redirected three times, or not at all.

The way to solve this problem is with the use of the HTTP HEAD verb.  Here is how I solved it in the case of IntellijIdea:

```
# This is the starting URL.
URL="https://download.jetbrains.com/product?code=IIC&latest&distribution=linux"
echo "URL: $URL"

# Issue HEAD requests until the actual target is found.
# The result contains the target location, among some irrelevant stuff.
LOC=$(wget --no-verbose --method=HEAD --output-file - $URL)
echo "LOC: $LOC"

# Extract the URL from the result, stripping the irrelevant stuff.
URL=$(cut "--delimiter= " --fields=4 <<< "$LOC")
echo "URL: $URL"

# Optional: download the actual file.
wget "$URL"
```