# wget: don't follow redirects if it points to location X, otherwise do

Tags: linux, bash, http, redirect, wget

As I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662943/wget-dont-follow-redirects) redirection can be easily turned of by `--max-redirect 0`. But what in case when there is two kinds of redirection: good one and the bad one.

In my case good redirection is:

http://someaddres.com/888.html -> http://someaddres.com/some-string-in-url-describing-page.html

where bad redirection is:

http://someaddres.com/555.html -> http://someaddres.com/

What can I do to fallow only good redirections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Thor84no said, one solution can parse response. This is mine:

```
REDIRECTED_TO=`wget --max-redirect 0 $ADDRESS 2>&1 | grep "Location" | sed 's|.*\(http://.*/.*\) .*|\1|'`

if [ "$REDIRECTED_TO" != "$BAD_REDIRECTION" ]; then wget $REDIRECTED_TO; fi
```

Answer (score 2):

The only way I can think of off the top of my head would be to turn off redirects as you've said, then parse the response (I suggest using `sed` or `grep`, but I'm sure there are other options) looking for a redirect request. You may need the parameter `--server-response` to get the headers depending on the method used for redirecting. If you find one, do a new wget to the redirect target (unless it's one you don't want to redirect to).