# wget - only output redirect url but no download

Tags: wget

I have a download link to a large file.
You need to be logged in to the site, so a cookie is used.
The download link redirects to another URL.
I'm able to download the file with wget but I only want the output of the "real" direct download link.
wget does exactly this before starting the download

```
Location: https://foo.com/bar.zip [following]
```

Is there a way to make wget stop and not actually downloading the file?
The solutions I found recommend redirecting to dev/null but this would still download the file. What I want is wget following the redirects but not actually starting the download.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [wget: don't follow redirects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662943/wget-dont-follow-redirects)

Comment: The possible duplicate has nothing to do with my question. I specifically WANT to follow redirects, so it's quite the opposite.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood, apologies. Does your URL redirect multiple times? In case it is only **one** redirect, following above’s solution should work: `wget --max-redirect 0 http://example.com/redirected`, and parse the output from the `Location:` field.

Answer (score 4):

I couldn't find a way to do it with `wget`, but I found a way to do it with `curl`:

```sh
curl https://openlibrary.org/data/ol_dump_latest.txt.gz -s -L -I -o /dev/null -w '%{url_effective}'
```

This only downloads the HEAD of the page (and sends it to `/dev/null`), so the file itself is never downloaded.

(src: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5300429/2317712 )

Answer (score 2):

Going off of @qqilihq's comment to the `curl` answer, this will first strip out the line starting with "Location:" then remove the "Location: " from the beginning and the " [following]" from the end using `awk`. Not sure if I would use this as it looks like a small change in the `wget` output could make it blow up. I would use the `curl` answer myself.

`wget --max-redirect=0 http://example.com/link-to-get-redirec-url-from 2>&1 | awk '/Location: /,// { print }' | awk '{print $2}'`